# asp.net authentication for any third party

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to make the user to be able of logging to my website using any accounts: Facebook, Yahoo, Windows Live, ...

It is something like Stack Overflow account authentication.

I need to do it with asp.net (.NET); how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short:

You have to get the api for each of those sites, and integrate them with your site.
They are mostly in JS (as far as i know) so you can use them with any language,

Here are some api links:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/

http://developer.yahoo.com/auth/

http://www.programmableweb.com/api/windows-live-id-web-authentication

http://openid.net/

Each provides examples on how to use them, so read up ;)

Good Luck!